# How to delete a branch in bitbucket with mercurial hg?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I opened a second branch (branch2) locally in hg and pushed it to bitbucket. After that i merged the two branches locally and pushed it again...I have branch2 still living on bitbucket. How do i delete branch2 on bitbucket?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried closing it? From `hg help branch`:

```
Use "hg commit --close-branch" to mark this branch as closed.
```

Answer (score 8):

Closing doesn't exactly *delete* a branch (remove all trace).

If you want to delete it, you need to `hg strip` it.

1. In Bitbucket, find the revision where the branch was created, and go to `Settings > Strip changesets > <Enter "Revision to strip">`.
2. Confirm the deletion of all the revisions attached to the revision you entered, then delete.

**NOTE:** This approach may not be so straight forward if you have merged.  This approach is more for "I have created a branch incorrectly, I want to delete it, and recreate it again using the same branch name."

Answer (score 1):

Using hg workbench, I lookup up the commit that started the new branch, right clicked and selected `## Copy Hash`.

Then I enabled the strip extension by adding the following to my mercurial.ini (located at `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`)

```
[extensions]
strip =
```

Finally I executed the strip command using the hash from my clipboard to remove the local branch:

```
hg strip 36012047aee7c08cdc4ede51293392c106a3d0b7
```